# Xor parity constraint with more than two variables

Tags: z3, z3py

I am using the following `Python` function to model `Xor` constraints with an arbitrary number of variables for *Microsoft's* `Z3` solver with `Python API`:

```
#  parity function
#  break up long input lists in two smaller lists
def odd(solver, lits):
    length = len(lits)
    check(length > 0, "Odd needs argument(s)")
    if length == 1:
        solver.add(lits[0])
    elif length == 2:
        solver.add(Xor(lits[0], lits[1]))
    elif length == 3:
        solver.add(Xor(lits[0], Xor(lits[1], lits[2])))
    elif length == 4:
        #  this symmetric form is much faster than the chained forms
        solver.add(Xor(Xor(lits[0], lits[1]), Xor(lits[2], lits[3])))
    else:
        aux = get_aux_variable()

        #  cf. http://www.gregorybard.com/papers/bard_thesis.pdf
        cut_len = 3
        odd(solver, lits[:cut_len] + [aux])
        odd(solver, [aux] + lits[cut_len:])

auxVariableIdx = 0

def get_aux_variable():
    global auxVariableIdx

    auxVariableIdx += 1
    aux = Bool('t%s' % auxVariableIdx)
    return aux
```

I've noticed that the overall solver performance depends quite a lot on the way, the smaller `Xor` sub-cases are modelled. Example: I am using "`Xor(Xor(a,b), Xor(c,d))`" to declare an `Xor` with four inputs. The alternative "`Xor(a,Xor(b,Xor(c,d)))`" turned out to be slower by a factor of ten for my examples.

Another example: It makes a big difference if the auxiliary switching variable created to link sub-expressions is added to the inputs lists at the front or at the back of the list.

> What is the recommended way to model `Xor` constraints with many variables in `z3py`?

Comment: There is no recommended model, xor constraints are just hard for DPLL (-like) solvers, see for instance all kinds of (attempts of) application on crypto problems. I suspect changing the random seed might have a similar effect on the runtime in this example.